# ¿Como guardar una imagen de cualquier formato en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mongodb, imagen, insert

He estado investigando la manera de poder guardar una imagen en python pero hasta el momento no he encontrado nada que me pueda servir, lo que necesito es saber que `import` tener y como guardar la imagen en python, esta imagen la guardare en una base de datos en mongodb, pero aun no se como guardar una imagen en python me podrian ayudar, lo mas cercano que he encontrado es esto:

[Guardar imagen en python 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228629/how-do-i-save-an-image-in-python-3-using-pil)

De antemano les agradeceria la ayuda.

**Actualización**

Gracias a @EdgarAlejandro logre terminar mi código que buscaba y se los quiero compartir

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Image
import pymongo
import base64

from PIL import Image, ImageOps
from pymongo import MongoClient
con = MongoClient()
db = con.test

image = 'masexito.jpg'

img = Image.open(image)
#img.save('/home/santiago/Documents/Python/img/exito2.jpg')
#encoded = base64.b64encode(img)
with open(image, "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

user = {
    'nombre' : 'Saul',
    'edad' : 38,
    'localidad' : 'Monterrey',
    'curp' : 'NDUBD88DND87',
    'imagen' : encoded_string
}

use = db.users
use.insert_one(user)

print 'Insertado Correctamente' + str(use.inserted_id)

for row in use.find():
    print row
```

**P.D.: Deben de tener instaladas las librerias correspondientes**

Comment: estas usando algún framework ?

Comment: No, no uso ningun framework apenas estoy empezado a desarrollar el codigo

Comment: Santiago, creo que deberías editar tu pregunta por que no es demasiado clara. ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? Una imagen tal como dices es un archivo físico y como cualquier otro, guardarlo es trivial, pero entiendo que no preguntas eso. Acaso el tema es como transformar un BLOB (binary large object) de mongodb a un archivo físico  y viceversa?

Comment: No, solo quiero saber como guardar una imagen en python, mencione lo de mongodb porque ya se como guardar datos en mongodb y solo quiero saber que necesito codificar para poder guardar una imagen en python es todo perdon si los confundi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

image = request.FILES['logo'] #imagen que usuario sube desde la web o
image = '/path/to/image.png'  #imagen de tu PC

#debes usar la variable image dependiendo si es desde la web o tu PC

img = Image.open(image)
img.save('path donde guardas')
```

Comment: Justo lo que buscaba, pero tengo una pregunta jejej, la variable que lo guarda es img o imagePath ?

Comment: img tiene la imagen y save es el nuevo path donde lo guardas

Comment: Ok ya entendi gracias :)